# Is there a way to integrate Properties View within the Eclipse Multipage editor?

Tags: eclipse, properties, view

I am trying to implement an Eclipse editor which consists of a design part, Palette part and the Properties part for the selected palette item. All in the same editor page.

After a long time of googling, I have come to know that there are no proper articles or examples for this issue. Is there some solution that I could get from anyone here?

The SWT Design editor implements this feature in its editor. However, I am unable to access its source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the properties view, you have to have three things:

- Your editor must define its `SelectionProvider (getSite().setSelectionProvider())`. A `SelectionProvider` is either a JFace `Viewer`, or can be any class that return a corresponding `ISelection` interface.
- The objects returned by the `ISelection` must either implement `IPropertySource` or return an `IPropertySource` adapter using the `getAdapter(IPropertySource.class)`.
- In multi-page editors you have to make sure, that the `SelectionProvider` also returns what expected.

For details about the first two point, see the following Eclipse Corner article: [Take control of your properties](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Properties-View/properties-view.html), or if you would like to use the Tabbed properties view seen in GMF editors, [The Eclipse Tabbed Properties View](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html).

Comment: Hi Zoltán, I am able to view the functional propertyView when I click an element in my editor. But the problem is, I want to implement the properties table from the propertyView within the same editor. All of the above steps you have mentioned works in implementing the relation between the editor and the PropertyView. But, I need the propertyView content function within the EditorPart. Thanks Dila

Comment: In this case, you should look at the org.eclipse.ui.packages.views.properties.PropertySheet class, and copy what you need. This way you can reuse the GUI of the built-in property sheet.